# How to add the same widget twice?

Tags: widgets

I noticed that if you put the same widget in two different widget slots (primary and secondary for instance) only the first one will appear on the page. The second slot will be empty.

How to solve that problem and allow my widget (a custom menu) to appear twice on my page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with that particular widget or if not that then your theme.

Try again with a default theme and one of the wp widgets.

Works fine with those.

Comment: Thanks anmari the problem was indeed my theme. I have multiple loops on my front page (each using its own WP_Query instance) but the last loop re-used the default WP_Query instance.

I made this loop use its own instance of WP_Query too, and the problem is gone.

I see absolutely no relationship between multiple instances of a custom menu widget and multiple uses of the default WP_Query object. So this problem will remain a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

Older widgets might not use the Widget API (from 2.8) or the proper function to allow for multiple instances (pre 2.8).

1. You can try and find a more updated plugin.
2. You can rewrite the plugin to use the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)
3. You can possibly add [this older function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_widget_control) into the current plugin with multiple `id_base`'s `wp_register_widget_control`

The latter is not recommended but might be easier to implement in your case.